# Any way to recover the deleted the VM instance created in DataProc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

In case any VM instance gets deleted accidentally then is there any way to recover it in Dataproc cluster. In case there is no way to recover a deleted VM instance then can we create a new VM instance and connect to an existing DataProc cluster?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to recover data on deleted VMs. Also manually removing workers carries a possibility of bricking the cluster. If your goal is to shrink the cluster we recommend option #1 below.

There's a few ways to add back a deleted VM:

1. Resize the cluster down and up using `gcloud dataproc clusters update --num-workers`, you'll want to ensure the deleted VM is in the set of VMs to be removed by downsize operation (this is not always possible)
2. From Developers Console go to `Compute > Instances` select any regular worker VM and clone it such that name matches the deleted VM.

Both of these approaches carry identical billing implications.